# JavaScript regular expression of wrap text

Tags: javascript, regex

I tried to wrap text using regular expression, to auto line break when detected \n or over the maximum of character each line, but here have some problem.

```
var str = ”The \na\nexample textttttttt, hello world, good bye.”

str.replace(/(?![^\n]{1,10}$)([^\n]{1,10})\s/g, '$1\n');
//replace line break when have \n or over maximum length
console.log(str);
```

The result

```
The
a
example
textttttttt,
hello
world,
good bye.
```

This regular expression can make a auto line break when detected \n or over maximum length (10) each line.

In line 3 of the result, the length of texttttttt, is over 10,
may I know how to prevent this problem? When the word is over than maximum length.

The result which I want

```
The
a
example
texttttttt
t, hello
world,
good bye.
```

Update

The recently result of my output was wrong, the true result:
It work event if the word over 10

```
The 

a

example te
xtttttttt,
 hello wor
ld, good b
ye.
```

Comment: You say when \n is detected. How the words The and example are in different line ? It is just in one string and less than 10 characters

Comment: yes, it work when the string have \n, my main problem is the word can’t split over 10 characters.

Comment: I think the output for third line should be `example te` and 4th line should `xtttttttt,` and so on.

Comment: check this - https://jsfiddle.net/9x8trma3/18/

Comment: Oh, my code is work too. My result output is wrong.

Comment: \n is already a line break and you just have to break on every ten characters. Does it solve your issue now ?

Answer (score -1):

You can use `Negative Lookahead` to check if you don't have the `\n` in front of character

```js
const str = "The \na\nexample textttttttt, hello world, good bye.";

const words = str.match(/(?:(?<!\\n).){1,10}/g);

console.log(words)
```